# .net FirebaseRealTime Exception occured while processing the request

Tags: c#, .net, firebase-realtime-database, maui

net 8 in a Maui project where I'm trying to fetch data from my FiB project, so far good but every time I try to get info from a collection is giving me this error:

> Exception occured while processing the request.
> Url: https://MyFibProject.firebaseio.com/note4Dev/.json

here is how I'm intending to get them.

```
private async void OnGetNote4DevCommand()
        {
            if (_fibAddChild != null)
            {
                var notes = await _fibAddChild.GetNotes();
                foreach (var n in notes)
                {
                    DevNotes.Add(n);
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my service

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<Note4DevModel>> GetNotes()
        {
            ObservableCollection<Note4DevModel> ResultList = new ObservableCollection<Note4DevModel>();
            try
            {

                var notes =  await client.Child("note4Dev").OnceAsListAsync<Note4DevModel>().ConfigureAwait(false);
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($" {ex.Message} {ex.Data}");
                
            }

            return ResultList;
        }
```

I'm not adding my notes to my observable object yet , funny part tho ... exception data contains successful response code and data

```
2023-12-09 20:34:59.728536-0600 MyAppMaui[28088:1016323] Response: {"-NlGTGGspOWO5pG_qonL":{"Date":"2023-12-09T20:05:38.788516-06:00","Message":"1231322"},"-NlGTbhfBDgcScorqxQS":{"Date":"2023-12-09T20:07:10.675811-06:00","Message":"121213"},"-NlGVF_bwxWq6Bbm6oVk":{"Date":"2023-12-09T20:14:20.238654-06:00","Message":"43535"}} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
```

can any one guide about what I'm doing wrong ? ty

[image]

Comment: Your status code returns OK. This might not be the issue which caused during accessing the data from the firebase.

Comment: I found some useful information about the issue. This might be a deserialization error. You can check this thread about ['Exception occured while processing the request.'](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet/issues/259) on the GitHub.